# Apache still using default SSL certificate for Virtual Host even after a real one has been installed

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am receiving 'Connection is Untrusted' errors when accessing my site from a browser over SSL.  I can see from the details it is using the default self-signed certificate from Apache, and not the real CA-signed certificate I have installed.

In the virtual host config for the site I have:

```
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/backup.domainname.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/backup.domainname.com.key
```

...where domainname is the actual domain of the site.  I have restarted Apache and it came back up ok.

What would be causing Apache to try and use the default self-signed certificate created when the OS was installed, rather than this real certificate specified in the virtual host config?  Does it matter which directory the .crt and .key files are stored in?

Comment: remember to use apache restart instead of graceful when working with SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the same error or are you seeing client negotiation warnings due to a missing Intermediate cert and associated `SSLCertificateChainFile` entry?

Another possibility is you are using a default apache implementation that is including the old cert directives somewhere higher up in your httpd.conf or in an included conf file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I added the SSLCertificateChainFile entry but it doesn't make a difference.  The certificate error detail still says 'The certificate is only valid for localhost.localdomain' as localhost.localdomain was the hostname I had set when I first installed the OS.

Comment: It is a default Apache implementation, and there is a separate file with SSL configuration details.  I tried commenting out the references in that file to the default self-signed key & cert, but then Apache would not restart.  In any case, it should be using the certificate I set for that virtual host rather than the default one right?  I would have thought the default one would only be used if there wasn't a certificate specified in the virtual host config and https was being used?

Comment: You'll want to replace any occurrence of your default cert directives with updated ones using your new certs.  You can probably keep using the included ssl file but comment out the cert entries and replace them with the new ones.

Comment: Thank you.  I've just realized there can only be one SSL per IP address on the server, and not one for each name-based virtual host... I think that's what was getting me confused.  I'll try it now.

Comment: Everything worked once I overwrote the links to default certificate in the conf.d/ssl.conf file with the links to the real one.  thanks!